# please let me know the nuance and teach me which is correct

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, terminology

This new sports complex is _________, so people can enjoy the games whatever the season is.
(A) encased (B) enclosed (C) encircled (D) enveloped

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you want is **indoor** (all definitions from https://dictionary.cambridge.org/):

> Happening, used, or existing inside a building

Of the 4 options you put forward, the closest is **enclosed**:

> Surrounded by walls, objects, or structures

*Encased* refers to something which is *completely* surrounded or covered by a typically solid surround. You would use it for a filling for a pie, for instance, or in the Cambridge dictionary example:

> The nuclear waste is encased in concrete before being sent for storage in disused mines.

*Encircled* refers specifically to a circle around an object. In your example you might use it to indicate that "the sport complex is *encircled* by a several rows of seats". notice it says nothing about it being covered or not.

*Enveloped* is more subtle. If you look at the definition it seems to imply "cover", but in reality it refers to less tangible/defined items: mist or fog, say, but also geometrical shapes, sound etc.